# How to do the correlation in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

We are trying to record the load report function of an application using LoadRunner Professional 2021. The report header generates the datetime at runtime, so we are not able to do the replay of the load report functionality.

We need to add the current datetime in the report header, but we are not able to do it,

The date-time is added at the runtime to the report header and then this becomes the window name. We need to call the window name to load the report, but we are not able to load the report.

Can you suggest a regex?

Original:

```
ctrx_sync_on_window("Transfer Report (07/05/21 11:40:28)", ACTIVATE, 7, 0, 1359, 642, "snapshot33", CTRX_LAST);
```

We tried:

```
ctrx_sync_on_window("Transfer Report {(##/##/## ##:##:##)}", ACTIVATE, 7, 0, 1359, 642, "snapshot33", CTRX_LAST);
```

We also tried many different regexes, still we were not able to append the current datetime with the word Transfer Report.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the below regex is working fine.
lr_save_datetime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",DATE_NOW -1,"newcurrentdatetime");
ctrx_sync_on_window("Transfer Report ({newcurrentdatetime})", ACTIVATE, 7, 0, 1359, 642, "snapshot33", CTRX_LAST);

Answer (score 0):

- Rather than regex, i would prefer Creating a parameter (Ctrl+L) with
  the required format of Date & time (07/05/21 11:40:28 -> dd/mm/YY
  HH:MM:ss) in the parameter list
- Pass this value in ctrx_sync_on_window which needs to be validated.
- This should resolve the issue.

PS : I do not exactly remember the notation for Date & time. You need to check and edit the same